# Retrieving random row using drupal database wrap functionality

Tags: database, drupal

I am writing a fairly simple 'roleplaying name generator' block for drupal6 and I have a myriad of start/middle/end options for names in a table.

I am looking for a simple way to retrieve a random row of each while staying with the drupal database wrapper functions.

It was not hard to find mysql-specific solutions but I would like to stay portable as I have no guarantee that my users will be running mysql.

Any pointers would be spiffy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7, the [SelectQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) class has a specific method for this, orderRandom() which you can use to be portable.

I guess for Drupal 6, the easiest solution is to write an "if ($GLOBALS['db_type'] == 'pgsql')" conditional statement and either use RAND() (mysql) or RANDOM() (pgsql). Almost nobody is using anything else and those who do are probably running a hacked version of Drupal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How portable do you need to be?

Conceptually, the solution is really pretty simple.

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

And, at that point, you can just take the first row as your random row. One problem is that different platforms use different functions. PostgreSQL (above) uses RANDOM(), MySQL uses RAND(). IIRC, SQL Server has a RAND() function, but used repeatedly within a single query it returns the same value. So SQL Server requires "ORDER BY NEWID();" (I could be wrong about SQL Server.)